# Enable file key plugin of MariaDB on CentOS 7.5

Tags: centos, centos7, mariadb

I'm trying to enable the file_key_management on MariaDB.

I'm working on CentOS 7.5 and MariaDB 15.1.
Here is the centos-release:

> CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

And the MariaDB version:

> Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB

I've used this commands to prepare the keys:

```
openssl rand -hex 16 >> /etc/mysql/keys
openssl rand -hex 16 >> /etc/mysql/keys
openssl rand -hex 16 >> /etc/mysql/keys
chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/keys
chmod 400 /etc/mysql/keys
```

After that, I've edited the `etc/mysql/keys` file to be in format:

```
1;key_1  
2;key_2
3;key_3
```

I encrypted the `etc/mysql/keys` file with `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha1 -k "password" -in /etc/mysql/keys -out /etc/mysql/keys.enc`. Last of all, I edited my `my.cnf` file to be like this:

```
[mysqld]
...

# File Key Management
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/keys.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = aes_cbc

[mysqld_safe]
...
```

After all that, when I reboot the mariadb service, it says the following:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

This is the MariaDB log:

```
180826 17:06:19 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
180826 17:06:19  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180826 17:06:20 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.59-MariaDB-38.11 started; log sequence number 429373685
180826 17:06:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
180826 17:06:20 [ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/file_key_management.so' (errno: 17, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
180826 17:06:20 [ERROR] Couldn't load plugins from 'file_key_management.so'.
180826 17:06:20 server_audit: MariaDB Audit Plugin version 1.4.3 STARTED.
180826 17:06:20 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'file_key_management_filename=/etc/mysql/keys.enc'
180826 17:06:20 [ERROR] Aborting

180826 17:06:20 server_audit: STOPPED
180826 17:06:20  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
180826 17:06:24  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 429373685
180826 17:06:24 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

180826 17:06:24 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

I cannot find how to download the `file_key_management.so` file to use it. Can somebody help me find any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get that MariaDB version string?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ```mysql -V```

Comment: Then you have somehow installed multiple versions of MariaDB. How did you do that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've done ```yum list installed | grep maria``` and I only get version 5.5.60

Comment: Indeed! So where did the version 5.5.59 come from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Dunno, also, when I do status on the mysql console, I get version 5.5.60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Encrypted data](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-encrypt-mariadb-data/) was added in the 10.1 series of MariaDB. As you have 5.5.60 there isn't this plugin available.

A [10.1](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos7-amd64--centos7&version=10.1) packages are available for Centos 7 (as are 10.2 and 10.3).